# SoapClient CreateItem return null

Tags: php, soap, imap, rhel

I got an app written on kohana fw. For some reasons I had to recompile php on linux server(rhel6) , and some processes that were working with ms exchange died.

New php was recompiled with this configuration options:

```
 ./configure  --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu 
 --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
 --target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu 
 --program-prefix= 
 --prefix=/usr      
 --exec-prefix=/usr      
 --bindir=/usr/bin      
 --sbindir=/usr/sbin      
 --sysconfdir=/etc      
 --datadir=/usr/share      
 --includedir=/usr/include      
 --libdir=/usr/lib64      
 --libexecdir=/usr/libexec      
 --localstatedir=/var      
 --sharedstatedir=/var/lib      
 --mandir=/usr/share/man      
 --infodir=/usr/share/info      
 --with-libdir=lib64      
 --with-config-file-path=/etc      
 --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d      
 --disable-debug    
 --enable-shared      
 --disable-rpath      
 --without-pear      
 --without-bz2      
 --with-exec-dir=/usr/bin      
 --with-freetype-dir=/usr      
 --with-png-dir=/usr      
 --with-xpm-dir=/usr      
 --enable-gd-native-ttf      
 --without-gdbm  
 --with-gettext  
 --with-gmp  
 --with-iconv  
 --with-jpeg-dir=/usr  
 --with-openssl  
 --with-pcre-regex=/usr  
 --with-zlib  
 --with-layout=GNU  
 --enable-exif  
 --enable-ftp  
 --enable-magic-quotes  
 --enable-sockets  
 --enable-sysvsem  
 --enable-sysvshm  
 --enable-sysvmsg  
 --enable-ucd-snmp-hack  
 --enable-shmop  
 --enable-calendar  
 --without-sqlite  
 --with-libxml-dir=/usr  
 --with-xml   
 --enable-xml  
 --with-system-tzdata  
 --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs  
 --without-gd  
 --disable-dom  
 --disable-dba  
 --without-unixODBC  
 --enable-pdo  
 --disable-xmlreader  
 --disable-xmlwriter  
 --enable-sqlite3  
 --with-sqlite3  
 --disable-phar  
 --disable-fileinfo  
 --enable-json  
 --without-pspell  
 --enable-wddx=shared   
 --with-curl  
 --disable-posix  
 --disable-sysvmsg  
 --disable-sysvshm  
 --disable-sysvsem  
 --with-pdo-informix=/opt/IBM/informix  
 --enable-intl  
 --enable-mbstring  
 --with-mysql  
 --with-mysqli  
 --enable-pcntl  
 --with-pdo-mysql  
 --with-pspell  
 --with-libedit  
 --with-readline  
 --enable-shmop  
 --with-snmp  
 --enable-soap  
 --enable-sockets   
 --without-pdo-pgsql  
 --with-pdo-dblib   
 --with-imap=/usr/local/src/imap-2007e  
 --with-imap-ssl
```

Well, what I know is that local copy of project on windows still send mails, but server version doesn't. I searched all logs and not found any valuable errors, but only in access logs, and only with time of requests, and n comments.

When I searched in code, to find out where code fails, I got to the point of creation item:

```
 $response = $this->client->CreateItem($CreateItem);

 var_dump($response);die();
```

That returns null. On local machine here goes object.

p.s: for more info provide the only trace...((

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Trying to get property of non-object' in /opt/project/www/modules/exchangeclient/classes/exchangeclient.php:446
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/project/www/modules/exchangeclient/classes/exchangeclient.php(446): Kohana_Core::error_handler(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/opt/project/ww...', 446, Array)
#1 /opt/project/www/application/classes/controller/backend/mail.php(284): ExchangeClient-&gt;send_message('krutitskiyvn@vt...', '???????????????...', 'action_bcosale()
#3 /opt/project/www/system/classes/kohana/request/client/internal.php(118): ReflectionMethod-&gt;invoke(Object(Controller_Backend_Mail))
#4 /opt/project/www/system/classes/kohana/request/client.php(64): Kohana_Request_Client_Internal-&gt;execute_request(Object(Request))
#5 /opt/project/www/system/classes/kohana/request.php(1138): Kohana_Request_Client-&gt;execute(Object(Request))
#6 /opt/project/www/index.php(115): Kohana_Request-&gt;execute()

#7 {main}"
```

What it might be and how to check?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's silly, but that was cache problems... Reboot of the server helped =)